# How to use 3 dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm doing some image processing in php and normally I never use array in php before.

I have to keep the value of rgb value of hold image in 3 dimensional array.

For example, `rgbArray[][][]`

the first `[]` is represent th weight, the second`[]` use to keep height and the last one is use to keep either red,greed or blue. How can i create an array in php that can keep this set of value.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for a two dimensional array:

```
$rgbArray[$index] = array('weight'=>$weight, 'height'=>$height, 'rgb'=>$rgb);
```

But here is a 3 dimensional array that could make sense for what you're asking.

```
$rgpArray[$index] = array('red'=>array('weight'=>$weight, 'height'=>$height),
                          'green'=>array('weight'=>$weight, 'height'=>$height),
                          'blue'=>array('weight'=>$weight, 'height'=>$height));
```

Comment: Please give me an example for use it. For example how can I assign the value to rgbArray[1][1][red]

Comment: Just quote 'red'.  So you statement would be $rgbArray[1][1]['red'] = $value;  It would read in English something like "The value of rgbArray with weight 1, height 1 and rgb red is value."

Answer (score 2):

If yours array

```
$rgbArray = array('red'=>array('weight'=>$weight, 'height'=>$height),
                  'green'=>array('weight'=>$weight, 'height'=>$height),
                  'blue'=>array('weight'=>$weight, 'height'=>$height));
```

Then you can assign the value to rgbArray like

```
$weight = $rgbArray['red']['weight']
$height = $rgbArray['red']['height']
```

If yours array

```
$rgbArray = array('red'=>array($weight, $height),
                  'green'=>array($weight, $height),
                  'blue'=>array($weight, $height));
```

Then you can assign the value to rgbArray like

```
$weight = $rgbArray['red'][0]
$height = $rgbArray['red'][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Define three-dimensional array

```
$threeDimArray = array(array(
                        array("reza", "daud", "ome"),
                        array("shuvam", "himel", "izaz"),
                        array("sayanta", "hasib", "toaha")));
```

#### Printing three-dimensional array

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($threeDimArray); $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j < count($threeDimArray[$i]); $j++) { 
        for ($k=0; $k < count($threeDimArray[$i][$j]); $k++) { 
            echo $threeDimArray[$i][$j][$k];
            echo " ";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a little confuse **rgbArray[1][1][red]**, it looks like you want this:

```
$rgbArray = array(1 => array(1 => array('red' => 'value')));
echo $rgbArray[1][1]['red']; // prints 'value'
```

I recommend, as [PMV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448579/pmv) said, to do next:

```
$rgbArray = array('weight' => 1, 'height' => 1, 'rgb' => 'red' );
```

or

```
$rgbArray = array();
$rgbArray['weight'] = 1; // int value
$rgbArray['height'] = 1; // int value
$rgbArray['rgb'] = 'red'; // string value
```

If it's not what you want please be more specific in order to be helped.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ThrdArray = array(
            array(
                    array("red","green","blue"),
                    array("cyan","pink","violet"),
                    array("brown","white","black"),
                )
            );
            echo "<br><br>";
            var_dump($ThrdArray);
            echo "<br><br>";
            for ($i=0;$i<count($ThrdArray);$i++){
               echo "<br><br><p><b> colors :-".$i+1 ."</p></b>";
               echo "<ul>";
            for ($j=0;$j<count($ThrdArray[$i]);$j++){
                echo "<li type='square'>". $j+1 ."<br>";
                for ($k=0;$k<count($ThrdArray[$i][$j]);$k++){
                    echo "<li type='disk'>".$ThrdArray[$i][$j][$k]."</li>";
                }
                echo "</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            }
            unset($i,$j,$k);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This a beginner friendly and you can understand from this pretty clearly